# Event Handlers in React Stateless Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to figure out an optimal way to create event handlers in React stateless components. I could do something like this:

```
const myComponent = (props) => {
    const myHandler = (e) => props.dispatch(something());
    return (
        <button onClick={myHandler}>Click Me</button>
    );
}
```

The drawback here being that every time this component is rendered, a new "myHandler" function is created. Is there a better way to create event handlers in stateless components that can still access the component properties?

Comment: useCallback -

const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);

Returns a memoized callback.

Answer (score 65):

Applying handlers to elements in function components should generally just look like this:

```
const f = props => <button onClick={props.onClick}></button>
```

If you need to do anything much more complex it's a sign that either a) the component shouldn't be stateless (use a class, or hooks), or b) you should be creating the handler in an outer stateful container component.

As an aside, and undermining my first point slightly, unless the component is in a particularly intensively re-rendered part of the app there's no need to worry about creating arrow functions in `render()`.

Comment: how does this avoid creating a function every time the stateless component is rendered?

Comment: The code example above just shows a handler being applied by reference, no new handler function is created on render of that component. If the outer component created the handler using `useCallback(() => {}, [])` or `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)`, then the component would be getting the same handler reference each render too which could help with using `React.memo` or `shouldComponentUpdate` (but this is only relevant with intensively re-rendered numerous/complex components).

Answer (score 55):

Using the new React hooks feature it could look something like this:

```
const HelloWorld = ({ dispatch }) => {
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(something())
  })
  return <button onClick={handleClick} />
}
```

`useCallback` creates a memoised function, meaning a new function will not be regenerated on each render cycle.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

However, this is still at proposal stage.

Comment: React Hooks have been released in React 16.8 and are now an official part of React. So this answer works perfectly.

Comment: Just to note that the recommended exhaustive-deps rule as part of eslint-plugin-react-hooks package says: "React Hook useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument.", so, yeah, in this case an empty array should be passed as a second argument.

Comment: In your example above there's no efficiency gained using `useCallback` - and you are still generating a new arrow function every render (the arg passed to `useCallback`). `useCallback` is only useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders. If you're just applying the callback to a HTML element like button then don't use `useCallback`.

Comment: @JedRichards I share your concerns. But in practice I see positive results.
I've a list and pass a callback as <Item callback={callback}> from the parent.
On some action in other component my list is rerendering because of this callback = () => dispatch(action);. 
Without useCallback every item took 1.40ms to rerender. With useCallback as above - 80µs just to do some update magic (but console before return is not invoked -> so no rerender).

Comment: @JedRichards although a new arrow function is created on each render, the DOM doesn't need to be updated which should save time

Comment: As this answer is currently written, it won't work well if the `dispatch` prop value is not always the same function.  `dispatch` should be added as a dependency by passing it in an array as a second parameter to `useCallback`:  `useCallback(..., [dispatch])`

Comment: @herman With an undefined dependency array `useCallback` will run every render, so if `dispatch` changes it should pick up the new value every time. Only if the empty dependency array `[]` was used could things get out of sync.

Comment: @JedRichards interesting, I couldn't find that in the docs though.  It seems a bit strange as I don't see why you'd ever use `useCallback` that way: what's the difference between using it with an undefined dependency array and not using it at all?

Comment: @herman There's no difference at all (aside from a small performance penalty), which is why this answer we're commenting under is a bit suspect :) Any hook that doesn't have a dependency array will run after every update (it's discussed near the start of the useEffect docs). Like I mentioned, you'd pretty much only want to use useCallback if you want a stable/memoized ref to a callback function you're planning on passing to a child component that's intensively/expensively re-rendered, and referential equality is important. Any other usage, just create a new function in render each time.

Comment: @JedRichards OK so bottomline is that if you need memoization at all, at least you should specify a dependency array (even if it's an empty one)

Answer (score 17):

How about this way :

```
const myHandler = (e,props) => props.dispatch(something());

const myComponent = (props) => {
 return (
    <button onClick={(e) => myHandler(e,props)}>Click Me</button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Good thought! Sadly, this doesn't get around the issue of creating a new function every render call: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Comment: @aStewartDesign any solution or update for this issue?
really glad to hear it, because I'm facing the same problem

Comment: have a parent regular component that has the implementation of the myHandler and then simply pass it to the sub-component

Comment: i guess there is no better way that this one so far (July 2018) , if any one found some thing cool , pls let me know

Comment: why not `<button onClick={(e) => props.dispatch(e,props.whatever)}>Click Me</button>` ? I mean, dont wrap it in a myHandler func.

Comment: if I make convert my functional component to class component, should solve this problem. but I am not sure that if it is the appropriate use case to use class component

Answer (score 6):

If the handler relies on properties that change, you will have to create the handler each time since you lack a stateful instance on which to cache it. Another alternative which may work would be to memoize the handler based on the input props.

Couple implementation options
[lodash._memoize](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#memoize)
[R.memoize](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#memoize)
[fast-memoize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-memoize)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my simple favorite products list implemented with react and redux writing in typescript. You can pass all arguments you need in the custom handler and return a new `EventHandler` which accepts origin event argument. It's `MouseEvent` in this example.

Isolated functions keep jsx cleaner and prevent from breaking several linting rules. Such as `jsx-no-bind`, `jsx-no-lambda`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DispatchProp, Dispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { removeFavorite } from './../../actions/favorite';

interface ListItemProps {
  prod: Product;
  handleRemoveFavoriteClick: React.EventHandler<React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>>;
}

const ListItem: React.StatelessComponent<ListItemProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    prod,
    handleRemoveFavoriteClick
  } = props;  

  return (
    <li>
      <a href={prod.url} target="_blank">
        {prod.title}
      </a>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleRemoveFavoriteClick}>&times;</button>
    </li>
  );
};

const handleRemoveFavoriteClick = (prod: Product, dispatch: Dispatch<any>) =>
  (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(removeFavorite(prod));
  };

interface FavoriteListProps {
  prods: Product[];
}

const FavoriteList: React.StatelessComponent<FavoriteListProps & DispatchProp<any>> = (props) => {
  const {
    prods,
    dispatch
  } = props;

  return (
    <ul>
      {prods.map((prod, index) => <ListItem prod={prod} key={index} handleRemoveFavoriteClick={handleRemoveFavoriteClick(prod, dispatch)} />)}
    </ul>    
  );
};

export default connect()(FavoriteList);
```

Here is the javascript snippet if you are not familiar with typescript:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DispatchProp, Dispatch, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { removeFavorite } from './../../actions/favorite';

const ListItem = (props) => {
  const {
    prod,
    handleRemoveFavoriteClick
  } = props;  

  return (
    <li>
      <a href={prod.url} target="_blank">
        {prod.title}
      </a>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleRemoveFavoriteClick}>&times;</button>
    </li>
  );
};

const handleRemoveFavoriteClick = (prod, dispatch) =>
  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(removeFavorite(prod));
  };

const FavoriteList = (props) => {
  const {
    prods,
    dispatch
  } = props;

  return (
    <ul>
      {prods.map((prod, index) => <ListItem prod={prod} key={index} handleRemoveFavoriteClick={handleRemoveFavoriteClick(prod, dispatch)} />)}
    </ul>    
  );
};

export default connect()(FavoriteList);
```

Comment: No, this has the same problem that you're recreating the function on every render.  All you've done is made it too complicated for the linter to track.

Answer (score 4):

### solution one mapPropsToHandler and event.target.

functions are objects in js so its possible to attach them properties.

```
function onChange() { console.log(onChange.list) }

function Input(props) {
    onChange.list = props.list;
    return <input onChange={onChange}/>
}
```

this function only bind once a property to a function.

```
export function mapPropsToHandler(handler, props) {
    for (let property in props) {
        if (props.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if(!handler.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                 handler[property] = props[property];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do get my props just like this.

```
export function InputCell({query_name, search, loader}) {
    mapPropsToHandler(onChange, {list, query_name, search, loader});
    return (
       <input onChange={onChange}/> 
    );
}

function onChange() {
    let {query_name, search, loader} = onChange;
    
    console.log(search)
}
```

this example combined both event.target and mapPropsToHandler. its better to attach functions to handlers only not numbers or strings. number and strings could be passed with help of DOM attribute like

```
<select data-id={id}/>
```

rather than mapPropsToHandler

```
import React, {PropTypes} from "react";
import swagger from "../../../swagger/index";
import {sync} from "../../../functions/sync";
import {getToken} from "../../../redux/helpers";
import {mapPropsToHandler} from "../../../functions/mapPropsToHandler";

function edit(event) {
    let {translator} = edit;
    const id = event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-id').value;
    sync(function*() {
        yield (new swagger.BillingApi())
            .billingListStatusIdPut(id, getToken(), {
                payloadData: {"admin_status": translator(event.target.value)}
            });
    });
}

export default function ChangeBillingStatus({translator, status, id}) {
    mapPropsToHandler(edit, {translator});

    return (
        <select key={Math.random()} className="form-control input-sm" name="status" defaultValue={status}
                onChange={edit} data-id={id}>
            <option data-tokens="accepted" value="accepted">{translator('accepted')}</option>
            <option data-tokens="pending" value="pending">{translator('pending')}</option>
            <option data-tokens="rejected" value="rejected">{translator('rejected')}</option>
        </select>
    )
}
```

#### solution two. event delegation

see solution one. we can remove event handler from input and put it to its parent that holds other inputs too and by the help delegation technique we can be use event.traget and mapPropsToHandler function again.

Comment: Bad practice ! A function should only serve its purpose, it is meant to execute logic on some parameters not to hold properties, just because javascript permits lots of creative ways to do the same thing doesn't mean you should let yourself use whatever works.

Answer (score 2):

Like for a stateless component, just add a function -

```
function addName(){
   console.log("name is added")
}
```

and it is called in the return as `onChange={addName}`

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a few functions in you props that you are worried about you can do this:

```
let _dispatch = () => {};

const myHandler = (e) => _dispatch(something());

const myComponent = (props) => {
    if (!_dispatch)
        _dispatch = props.dispatch;

    return (
        <button onClick={myHandler}>Click Me</button>
    );
}
```

If it gets much more complicated, I usually just go back to having a class component.

Answer (score 1):

After continuous effort finally worked for me.

```
//..src/components/atoms/TestForm/index.tsx

import * as React from 'react';

export interface TestProps {
    name?: string;
}

export interface TestFormProps {
    model: TestProps;
    inputTextType?:string;
    errorCommon?: string;
    onInputTextChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
    onInputButtonClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
    onButtonClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
}

export const TestForm: React.SFC<TestFormProps> = (props) => {    
    const {model, inputTextType, onInputTextChange, onInputButtonClick, onButtonClick, errorCommon} = props;

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div className="alert alert-danger">{errorCommon}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input
                                name="name"
                                type={inputTextType}
                                className="form-control"
                                value={model.name}
                                onChange={onInputTextChange}/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>                            
                            <input
                                type="button"
                                className="form-control"
                                value="Input Button Click"
                                onClick={onInputButtonClick} />                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                value='Click'
                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                onClick={onButtonClick}>
                                Button Click
                            </button>                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>        
    );    
}

TestForm.defaultProps ={
    inputTextType: "text"
}

//========================================================//

//..src/components/atoms/index.tsx

export * from './TestForm';

//========================================================//

//../src/components/testpage/index.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import { TestForm, TestProps } from '@c2/component-library';

export default class extends React.Component<{}, {model: TestProps, errorCommon: string}> {
    state = {
                model: {
                    name: ""
                },
                errorCommon: ""             
            };

    onInputTextChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const field = event.target.name;
        const model = this.state.model;
        model[field] = event.target.value;

        return this.setState({model: model});
    };

    onInputButtonClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if(this.validation())
        {
            alert("Hello "+ this.state.model.name + " from InputButtonClick.");
        }
    };

    onButtonClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if(this.validation())
        {
            alert("Hello "+ this.state.model.name+ " from ButtonClick.");
        }
    };

    validation = () => {
        this.setState({ 
            errorCommon: ""
        });

        var errorCommonMsg = "";
        if(!this.state.model.name || !this.state.model.name.length) {
            errorCommonMsg+= "Name: *";
        }

        if(errorCommonMsg.length){
            this.setState({ errorCommon: errorCommonMsg });        
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <TestForm model={this.state.model}  
                        onInputTextChange={this.onInputTextChange}
                        onInputButtonClick={this.onInputButtonClick}
                        onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}                
                        errorCommon={this.state.errorCommon} />
        );
    }
}

//========================================================//

//../src/components/home2/index.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import TestPage from '../TestPage/index';

export const Home2: React.SFC = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Home Page Test</h1>
    <TestPage />
  </div>
);
```

**Note:** for text box filed binding "name" attribute & "property name" (e.g: model.name) should be same then only "onInputTextChange" will work. 
"onInputTextChange" logic can be modified by your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
let __memo = null;
const myHandler = props => {
  if (!__memo) __memo = e => props.dispatch(something());
  return __memo;
}

const myComponent = props => {
  return (
    <button onClick={myHandler(props)}>Click Me</button>
  );
}
```

but really this is overkill if you don't need to pass the onClick to lower/inner components, like in the  example.