# How to organize actions that don't modify state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action

let's say I have a react component like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  print = () => {
    const { url } = this.props
    const frame = document.createElement('iframe')

    frame.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const win = frame.contentWindow

      win.focus()
      win.print()
      win.addEventListener('focus', () => document.body.removeChild(frame))
    })

    Object.assign(frame.style, {
      visibility: 'hidden',
      position: 'fixed',
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0
    })

    frame.src = url

    document.body.appendChild(frame)
  }

}
```

Basically, clicking a button calls the print function in the browser for the user. In a situation like this, do I still make this into a redux action like `DO_PRINT` that doesn't actually do anything to my redux state or do I just not bother with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular example, I would avoid creating a Redux action as there is no need for that `DO_PRINT` to update any state if it is only calling `window.print()`.

In fact, assuming you're creating a "Print button" component, I would redefine this as a dumb component. (See [differences between presentationl and container components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).)

```
import React from ‘react’;

const PrintButton = () => {
  const onClick = () => {
    window.print();
  };

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click Me</button>
};

export default PrintButton;
```

FYI, the code above might not be the most efficient way of declaring event handlers for stateless components as the function is potentilly called each time the component is rendered. There might be better (more efficient) ways ([described in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260595/event-handlers-in-react-stateless-components)) but that's beyond this question.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! My original post was a bit vague so I've updated my post with the actual code for my print function. In my case, I actually need to create a hidden `iframe` for my print in order to not open a new window. Do you still think I shouldn't make it into a redux action?

Comment: You're welcome! I see the additional code still does not involve any data/state, so the answer should still stand. That being said, I would avoid manipulating the DOM directly in React, and use components instead.

Comment: Hmm, I see. So what I'm doing here is making a temporary iframe, and calling print from it, and then deleting it. I don't think I would be able to do that with a component unless you mean just keeping one iframe alive and optionally rendering it based on if i click print or not?

Comment: Might be a little anti-pattern but you should be able to; I was thinking something along the lines of [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWRmjG) .